# redirect process output

Tags: c++, windows, console

I have 2 processes. I need proces1 to show what's also shown in process2.

I use c/c++ in Windows and the processes are console application.

I guess will use pipe. But how?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "also show?"  I assume process1 writes to stdout and process2 somehow needs access to that output?  So you'd run the two programs like this: `process1 | process2`.  In which case you just need to use `std::cout` in process1 and `std::cin` in process2 to do the reading (and possibly also write using `std::cout` again if you want the output of process1 to be visible in the terminal).